# Plop boot manager won't start because of missing HAL.DLL

Tags: windows-xp, boot, bootloader

I had this problem this summer where I was unable to start Plop boot manager from Windows XP boot menu (configured in `boot.ini`). The error message was something like this:

```
Windows could not start because the following file is missing or corrupt:
\system32\hal.dll
```

System integrity checks (`sfc /scannow`) and replacement/repair of DLLs (including `hal`) did not work.

Comment: If you have no good motivation for your downvote, I urge you, please stay quiet. It helps other readers to ignore it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimenting with boot flags in `boot.ini` and reading the very incomplete documentation on MSDN I found out that using a flag (or whatever they called it) for a boot option I could manually assign any .dll in system32 to act as `hal`. I think it was something like `/HAL=xyz`.

I tried doing this with a working boot option (Windows XP) and let it point to a copy that I made: `hal_original.dll`

That resulted in the same error as when I tried to boot Plop. Hmm.

After investigating some more it turns out that the DLL must conform to [an 8.3 filename](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename), but I had given it a 12 characters long name. I then looked at the boot entry for Plop, which referenced `plpbt4win.ldr`. That's nine characters long.

Renaming the `.ldr` to have a filename of eight or less characters made the `HAL.DLL` error disappear, and Plop finally booted.

Comment: @espectalll Glad it helped, that's why I made this Q&A. Consider voting up the question as well — someone thought it'd be funny to downvote it for no reason, minutes after it was submitted. Also, you could consider contacting the plop author about this bug so that he can get some insight into which environments/file systems this problem appears in.